# How to change urdu/arabic fonts on chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fonts, arabic

In my previous laptop, I had installed and configured the `'Noto Naksh Arabic UI'` font in custom font settings in both Windows 10 and ubuntu, and chrome was able to render the Urdu text in that custom font.

Now I have bought a new laptop with preinstalled Windows 10, and now when I am changing the font setting there is no difference. I still see the same fonts being rendered.

Websites like Twitter have a very bad font for the Urdu language and I want to customize it. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

1.Download and copy the font to folder C:\Windows\Fonts，if it is grey out, click TAB `show` .

2.Make sure your windows firewall and windows update service are in running state.

3.check the settings under Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts\Font settings

Comment: I tried all the three steps. It didn't resolve the issue.